# Monarchs Stormforth vs Number 59: Crooked Cook

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[The Monarchs Stormforth](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Monarchs_Stormforth):

> Once during this turn, if you would Tribute a monster for a Tribute
>   Summon, you can Tribute 1 monster your opponent controls even though
>   you do not control it. You can only activate 1 "The Monarchs
>   Stormforth" per turn. During the turn you activate this card, you
>   cannot Special Summon monsters from the Extra Deck.

[Number 59: Crooked Cook](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Number_59:_Crooked_Cook):

> 2 Level 4 monsters While you control no other cards on the field, this
>   card is unaffected by other cards' effects. Once per turn, during
>   either player's turn: You can detach 1 Xyz Material from this card;
>   destroy as many other cards you control as possible, then this card
>   gains 300 ATK until the end of this turn for each monster destroyed by
>   this effect and sent to the Graveyard.

If player A has Number 59: Crooked Cook on field and being unaffected by other card effected, can player B tribute it for tribute summon if used Monarchs Stormforth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With there being multiple answers already, I feel a little weird about posting one of my own... but if it's an essay needed to be convincing, then an essay there shall be.

## No, Player B Cannot Tribute Crooked Cook In This Scenario

The cornerstone of the confusion, as I understand it, is a false (albeit commonly made) equivalency between certain cards which handle this sort of interaction differently from one another. Specifically, the cards [The Monarchs Stormforth](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/The_Monarchs_Stormforth) and [Lava Golem](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Lava_Golem) are being regarded as "doing the same thing," when in fact there are fundamental separations between the two. These separations - which unfortunately are more nuanced than they ought to be, given the prevalence of the Kaijus - are the tools we will use to evaluate the problem at hand. Let us investigate.

**There is already an existing ruling for The Monarchs Stormforth, regarding Forbidden Lance:**

> A monster that has been affected by the effect of "Forbidden Lance" cannot be Tributed for a Tribute Summon using the effect of "The Monarchs Stormforth".

The question further raised here is, to quote OP,

```
Ok, but then it states that:
    This card can be activated even if your opponent does not control any monsters.
    This effect is not only applied to monsters your opponent controls when the effect resolves.
```

Is there a discrepancy here? Well, no - not really. Let us examine the effect of The Monarchs Stormforth:

> Once during this turn, if you would Tribute a monster for a Tribute Summon, you can Tribute 1 monster your opponent controls even though you do not control it.

It's important to recognize here that **this is not an effect being applied to monsters on the field at resolution - this is an effect that gives the player an additional "thing" to do for the duration of the turn.** The distinction, of course, being that any monsters summoned after the resolution of The Monarchs Stormforth are also legal tributes by its effect.

Here's the rub: even though this isn't an effect being applied to the tributed monster at the time of resolution, it's still the effect of a spell card. Any tributes of the opponent's monster by the effect of The Monarchs Stormforth are exactly that: *Tributes **by the effect of** The Monarchs Stormforth*. So, if a monster is unaffected by Spell Card effects, then it cannot be tributed by the effect of a Spell Card. By this reasoning alone, we have enough to see why Crooked Cook cannot be tributed in the given scenario - while Crooked Cook is unaffected by other card effects, it cannot be tributed by the effect of Spell cards - like The Monarchs Stormforth.

Now, while we have technically answered the original question, it would be worthwhile to address the "part 2" of the question that came up after the fact: "So why can monsters like 'Lava Golem' tribute unaffected cards?"

This is a detail that eludes the understanding of many players, across all skill levels - yet it is an extraordinarily important concept to grasp:

**Lava Golem can tribute unaffected cards because it is not using an effect to do so.**

Understandably, this throws a large number of people for a loop. We can show that the summon of Lava Golem, in fact, is not a monster effect by trying to determine which class of monster effect it would be classified under - and subsequently recognize that it meets the criteria for none of them.

According to Konami's [Problem-Solving Card Text](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Problem-Solving_Card_Text) rules,

> All card effects that make a Chain Link include a colon " : " or a semicolon " ; " somewhere in their text (possibly both). If a card effect does not use either, it does not make a Chain Link.

So, we know that the summon of Lava Golem does not create a chain, and thus cannot be an activated effect. Because it is not an activated effect, it immediately rules out all but one of the types of monster effects according to the [Official Rulebook](https://img.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/SD_RuleBook_EN_10.pdf) - all that remains is for Lava Golem's summon to be by a Continuous Effect, except...

> [A Continous Effect] is active while the Effect Monster Card is face-up on
>   the field. The effect starts when the face-up monster appears
>   on the field, and ends once that monster is gone or is no longer
>   face-up

Obviously, this cannot be the case - Lava Golem is in our hand when we go to summon it, so it doesn't meet the definition of a continuous effect. We have thus shown that Lava Golem's summon is not considered to be the application of a monster effect. So, what is it?

**Lava Golem, and cards like it (e.g. the Kaijus, Quickdraw Synchron, Santa Claws, Spell Striker, &c) have a Summoning Procedure that *the player* carries out.**

To my knowledge, there is no explicit documentation from Konami on this matter, so I can offer no official explanation. However, the concept is: the monsters tributed to summon Lava Golem are not tributed by a monster effect. The Spell banished from the GY to summon Spell Striker is not banished by a monster effect. The card sent from the hand to the GY to summon Quickdraw Synchron is not sent by a monster effect.

**The cards in these scenarios are tributed/banished/sent to GY by the *player*, not by any card or effect**, in exactly the same respect as Tuners/Non-Tuners are sent to GY for a Synchro Summon, or Link materials for a Link Summon, or "contact fusion" materials for a "contact fusion". It is not a card that is considered by the game state to be doing anything - it is you, the player. And because these methods are not considered to be card effects, no protection against them is offered to any card made unaffected by other card effects.

Hope this clears up any remaining confusion.

Comment: I truly respect your detailed explanation! From my understanding, Lava Golem (and other similar monsters) can be summoned because it's a *cost* (not an effect), that's why they're allowed. I almost selected your answer as correct, then your last paragraph (and specifically this line) changed my mind: `..It is not a card that is considered by the game state to be doing anything - it is you, the player.`. Well, now I'm reading Monarchs Stormforth's text (and specifically this line): `..you can Tribute 1 monster your opponent controls..`, it's exactly same as you said "it is you, the player"!

Comment: You know what, as you said some parts not explained/documented well by Konami rules, although game mechanics seems to work as you already explained. I'll select your answer as correct, but really looking forward for some official answer from Konami about Monarchs Stormforth vs Unaffected monsters

Comment: The critical distinction is that even though TMS is giving you, the player, the ability to do something, that ability is to do something "by the effect of" a card, rather than "as part of the inherent summoning procedure for" a card.

Comment: You won't get any TCG official rulings. There are already OCG rulings and I recently asked OCG about this subject. I have the e-mails but I don't see a good reason to put them here, since there are database rulings and it should be on wiki.

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be tributed. If the player attempts to apply the effect of "Monarchs Stormforth" on an opponent's monster, it has to be on a monster that can be affected.

Comment: For something concrete: The Monarchs Stormforth [has a ruling](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:The_Monarchs_Stormforth) vs forbidden lance that applies quite nicely here. It can be generalized to the way you worded it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Shinji-san is correct, but seems not to convince you. So let met add another bit of context.

A more recent meta relevant of this situation would be masterpiece the true dracoslayer/metaltron vs monarchs stormforth. For these examples I found the folowing OCG ruling (it is ruled the same in tcg at tournaments en ycs) They are written with their OCG name:

https://ygorganization.com/ocg-020917-rulings/

> My opponent Tribute Summoned a Dozen Da’at Metatron, the True Draco
>   Meksoldier by Tributing 1 monster, 1 Continuous Spell Card, and 1
>   Continuous Trap Card. In this situation, if I activated The Monarchs
>   Stormforth, can I Tribute my opponent’s Dozen Da’at Metatron, the True
>   Draco Meksoldier for a Tribute Summon? A: In this scenario, since your
>   opponent’s Dozen Da’at Metatron, the True Draco Meksoldier was Tribute
>   Summoned by Tributing 1 monster, 1 Continuous Spell Card, and 1
>   Continuous Trap Card, it is unaffected by the effects of monsters,
>   Spell Cards, and Trap Cards. Since it is unaffected by the effect of
>   The Monarchs Stormforth, you cannot Tribute it in place of your own
>   monsters when performing a Tribute Summon.

So the monster needs to be affected by spells to allow it to be tributed via stormforth.
The example of Lava Golem you give (and kaijus will be the same) are different. For these cards the tribute is a cost not an effect, so being unaffected by monster effects is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I found some rule that might be similar to this case [here](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Lair_of_Darkness).

> Q: "Lair of Darkness" is face-up in my Field Zone. In this situation,
>   if there is a face-up "Hunter Dragon" on my opponent's field that is
>   unaffected by Spell effects due to the effect of "Forbidden Lance",
>   can I activate a card such as "Grinning Grave Virus" and apply the
>   effect of "Lair of Darkness", so that I Tribute that opponent's
>   "Hunter Dragon" for the cost?
>
> A: In this scenario, since your opponent's "Hunter Dragon" is
>   unaffected by the effects of Spell Cards, it is also unaffected by the
>   effect of "Lair of Darkness" that allows you to Tribute it when
>   activating a card or effect. Therefore, in this scenario, you cannot
>   Tribute that "Hunter Dragon" when activating a card or effect.

Lava Golem, Kaijus, Quickdraw Synchron, Santa Claws, Spell Striker, etc. are monsters. But Lair of Darkness is a spell card with similar effect to Monarchs Stormforth.

Comment: Yes, but what makes "The Monarchs Stormforth" ruling harder is that the card already resolved and is not even on the field. But they are similar, yes.